# Show that $|f(z_1)|=|f(z_2)|≤|z_1|^2=|z_2|^2$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f\in H(B(0,1))$, $f(0)=0$, $f(B(0,1))\subset B(0,1)$. Suppose there are 2 different points $z_1$,$z_2\in B(0,1)$, s.t. $|z_1|=|z_2|$, $f(z_1)=f(z_2)$. Show that $|f(z_1)|=|f(z_2)|≤|z_1|^2=|z_2|^2$.

---

I have used the Schwarz-Pick Proposition to prove that $|f(z_1)|=|f(z_2)|≤|z_1|=|z_2|$ directly, but that is not enough.
Thank you for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(z_1)=f(z_2)=\alpha$. Let $$g(z) = \frac{f(z) - \alpha}{1-\overline{\alpha} f(z)}.$$ Then $\lvert g(0) \rvert = \lvert \alpha \rvert$, $\lvert g(z) \rvert \leq 1$ and $g(z_1)=g(z_2)=0$. Then by the maximum principle $$\lvert g(z) \rvert \leq \left \lvert \frac{(z - z_1)(z-z_2)}{(1-\overline{z_1}\, z)(1-\overline{z_2} \, z)} \right \rvert.$$ Taking $z=0$ shows $\rvert \alpha \rvert \leq \lvert z_1z_2 \rvert$.

**Edit:** The inequality above is fairly standard and well worth the effort to understand.  The right hand side is a [Blaschke product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaschke_product). It has the property that it vanishes in $z_1$ and $z_2$ and has norm one on the unit circle.  Then $g(z)$ divided by this Blaschke product is holomorphic and the quotient has norm $\leq 1$ by the maximum principle (it has this bound on the unit circle).

Comment: How to conclude the 4th line by maximum principle?

Comment: @Ivan Too long for a comment. I edited the answer.

Comment: Your explanation is clear. Thank you!